# Using uninitilized variable in a method

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm writing a simple program within which a dynamic array is to be created. The function that is being used to create said array is in a second .cpp file, attached as a user-made library. Unfortunatelly Visual Studio pops an error saying that the program can't use uninitialized variable. I feel like it's a really easy problem to solve, but I don't know how to get through it. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
int i = 5, j = 6;
string** Array;
createDefStruct(Array, i, j);

/*for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
{
    for (int m = 0; m < j; m++)
    {
        Array[i][j] = "YIKES";
        cout << Array[i][j] << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;
}*/
deleteDefStruct(Array, i);
return 0;
}
```

The createDefStruct function:

```
void createDefStruct(string** Arr, int varAttribCount, int varCount)
{
    Arr = new string * [varAttribCount+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < varAttribCount+1; i++)
    Arr[i] = new string[varCount];
}
```

How do I go about initilizing a variable?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show a [mcve], in particular the definition of `createDefStruct`.

Comment: I've just added the definition

Comment: You pass `Array` by value. Any changes to it that `createDefStruct` makes are not visible to the caller. In `main`, `Array` is still uninitialized. Consider: `void f(int x) { x = 42; } int y = 0; f(y); // y is still zero` Read about passing by value and by reference in your favorite C++ textbook. Alternatively, you could have `createDefStruct` return the pointer it initialized, rather than taking it as a parameter.

Comment: Ohh, that makes more sense. Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that instead of returning your array from the function you passed the array into the function as parameter. This mean that the variable is uninitialised in main (even though it is initiialised in createDefStruct). Rewrite like this

```
string** createDefStruct(int varAttribCount, int varCount)
{
    string** Arr = new string * [varAttribCount+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < varAttribCount+1; i++)
        Arr[i] = new string[varCount];
    return Arr;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5, j = 6;
    string** Array = createDefStruct(i, j);
    ...
```

In general when you want a function to return a value you use `return` from inside the function to return that value. When you want to pass a value into a function you use a parameter. In your `createDefStruct` function `varAttribCount` and `varCount` are the parameters but the array should be a return value.

Comment: Thank you! This looks a lot better